# Tamper packet of my friends https website

Tags: http, https, tcp, proxy, fiddler

is it possible to tamper a packet of my friends website??

Website https://www.example.com sends a request to sub domain https://api.example.com
I want to tamper the response (it is static response, doesn't change) from another server.

so I want to make the client connect to my own server instead of https://api.example.com (without proxying https://www.example.com) but it is https, I don't have to know what the client sent, I just want the client to be able to read the none encrypted data that is sent from my server instead o https://api.example.com, I am trying to avoid downloading any type of file to the client machine, I rather keep everything server sided

Note: the website forces https connection

I tried to proxy https://api.example.com to my server by adding `127.0.0.1 api.example.com` to my hosts file, but it doesn't help because when my server responds, the client can't read none (`http`) encrypted response

Comment: If you want to perform https interception using a proxy like Fiddler you have to install the root CA certificate of the used proxy on the client system as trusted root CA certificate. That is necessary because otherwise https will block the connection as the "server" (hence the proxy) is untrusted.

Comment: @Robert can you show me some resources i could start my research at? How can i generate my own CA cert, and how can i use it to decode packets and forward them to the client and the website?

Comment: Fiddler and mitmproxy are well documented and they already generate necessary https certificates on-the-fly. So you just have to learn using what you have correctly.

Comment: @Robert i want to share this proxy, i cant share fiddler, and fiddler core is not free, i tried mitmproxy but i have trouble installing certificate

Comment: @Robert and these are are client sided tools, not server sided :/

Comment: Proxys like mitmproxy are usually used on client side because it is very easy to change proxy configuration on client side. But you can use mitmproxy in transparent mode on any host between our client and the server. That requires iptables configuration. And installation of mitmproxy certificate is well documented: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/ BTW: You can't modify traffic on server side because you don't have access to your frieds web server and your own web server is not used unless you change something on client side.

Comment: @Robert thank you for providing that link, i looked for it like 2weeks ago and couldnt find certificate documentation, but i am wondering wouldnt it be possible to do something like this:

client goes to ``http://www.myproxyweb.com`` (proxy server)

, the proxy server sends request to ``https://api.example.com`` (main server)

, the main server responds with some content to the proxy server

, the proxy server receive the content, decrypts it, and sends it back to the clients browser